# Not able to insert in mysql database phpyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

I recieve the echo before the bind_param statment but not after it

```
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO restaurants(unique_id, name, type, longitude, latitude, value_for_money, cleanliness, view, atmosphere, staff created_at) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, NOW())");

    echo "ezzat wasal";

    $stmt->bind_param("sssddiiiii", $uuid, $name, $type, (double)$longitude, (double)$latitude, (int)$value_for_money, (int)$cleanliness, (int)$view, (int)$atmosphere, (int)$staff);
    echo "ana zeh2et";
```

Comment: If you're using `bind_param`, which is a good thing, you shouldn't have to force-cast all those values.

Comment: What is the error output?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a comma between `staff` and `created_at`. Also I would suggest quoting all column names in the query (because some of them are reserved words in mySQL: name, type, view):

```
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `restaurants`
(`unique_id`, `name`, `type`, `longitude`, `latitude`, `value_for_money`,
 `cleanliness`, `view`, `atmosphere`, `staff`, `created_at`)
 VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, NOW())");
```

Comment: If that slipped through, [time to turn on `mysqli` exceptions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14578243/turning-query-errors-to-exceptions-in-mysqli).